# Для чего предназначены метки TODO в программе php storm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Для чего предназначены метки TODO в программе php storm?

Answer (score 1):

Для того, что бы помечать те места, где нужно "доделать"/"дописать". Многие IDE умеют находить подобные места автоматически и предоставляют разные удобства.

Answer (score 0):

[TODO в PhpStorm](http://blog.brainf.net/soft/todo-v-phpstorm/)